# Appcelerator - ListView error (only in Android)

Tags: android, listview, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am developing an app with Appcelerator framework (using Appcelerator Studio), but I have encountered aproblem without a solution (yet).

I am creating a list with all the countries in the world and their related phone prefix, i.e. "*United States +1*", "*United Kingdom +44*" and so on. I am using a **ListView**, since the user will have to choose one. On iOS everything works great, but when I run the app inside my Android phisical device, the **ListItems** are all presents, but not their text. What I mean is that, in iOS I see all the countries and their ccorresponding name in each line. In Android I see that there are 150+ lines inside my ListView, I can click on those lines, the application will choose the corresponding country, but **I don't see the printed text in the rows**.

I am using an **ItemTemplate**, and then I create (with Javascript) a **ListSection** to which I add the elements (adding them dynamically using the bindId property).

I've seen that other applications built with Appcelerator don't have this problem, so I am trying to figure out where I am wrong.

**countryList.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" id="win_firstStart_countryList">
        <ListView id="ListView_prefixes">
            <SearchBar id="searchBar_countries"/>
            <Templates>
                <ItemTemplate id="countryCodeTempl" name="countryCodeTempl">
                    <Label id="label_countryName"/>
                    <Label id="label_countryPrefix"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Templates>
        </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**countryList.tss**

```
"#ListView_prefixes": {
        "left": "0.00%",
        "top": "0%",
        "defaultItemTemplate": "countryCodeTempl"
    },
"#countryCodeTempl": {
    "color": "#000000",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
 },
 "#label_countryName": {
    "color": "#000000",
    "font": {fontSize:'18dp',fontFamily:'',fontStyle:'',fontWeight:''},
    "left": "3%",
    "top": "4dp",
    "bindId": "countryName",
    "height": Ti.UI.SIZE,
    "width": "45%",
    "backgroundColor": "#ff0000",
 },
 "#label_countryPrefix": {
    "bindId": "countryPrefix",
    "top": "4dp",
    "width": "45%",
    "height": Ti.UI.SIZE,
    "color": "#000000",
    "font": {fontSize:'18dp',fontFamily:'',fontStyle:'',fontWeight:''},
    "right": "3%",
    "textAlign": "right"
 },
 "#win_firstStart_countryList": {
    "left": "0.00%",
    "top": "0%",
    "height": "100%",
    "width": "100.00%",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
 }
```

**countryList.js**

```
var countrySection = Ti.UI.createListSection({});
var items = [];
var db = Ti.Database.open(DB_NAME);
var query = db.execute("SELECT country_code, country_name, country_prefix from countries");
while (query.isValidRow()) {
    items.push({
        countryName: { text: query.fieldByName('country_name') },
        countryPrefix: { text: "+ " + query.fieldByName('country_prefix') },
        properties: {
                title: query.fieldByName('country_name'),
                itemId: query.fieldByName('country_code'),  
                searchableText: query.fieldByName('country_name'),
                caseInsensitiveSearch: true
            }
    });
    query.next();
}
query.close();
db.close();

countrySection.setItems(items);
$.ListView_prefixes.sections = [countrySection];
$.ListView_prefixes.searchView = $.searchBar_countries;

$.searchBar_countries.addEventListener('change', function(e){
     $.ListView_prefixes.searchText = e.value;
});
```

Do you have an idea about why I cannot see the `countryName` and `countryPrefix` inside my ListItems only in Anddroid devices?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where is the problem. I think is a bug of Appcelerator Studio. When you set the "bindId" property, you cannot set in the .tss file, but you have to set directly inside the ItemTemplate element. In my case I did

```
<Label id="label_countryName"/>
<Label id="label_countryPrefix"/>
```

Instead, in order to let it work, **I should have write the following code**:

```
<Label bindId="countryName" id="label_countryName"/>
<Label bindId="countryPrefix" id="label_countryPrefix"/>
```